# What is the difference between cycle and “circle”?

Tags: word-usage

I’m Chinese, and it’s hard for me to distinguish the difference between the terms **cycle** and **circle**. Both of them mean **round** and **circulation** as far as I understand, but what’s the difference?

Comment: I don't think the meanings of the words is that simple. Example sentences need to be added to understand specific usage. It is hard to generalize since most words have more than one meaning or usage.

Answer (score 4):

[Cycle](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cycle) refers to a period of time or *"a group of events that happen in a particular order, one following the other, and are often repeated"*, while [circle](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/circle) is a round shape figure.

Comment: Would be nice if you could add references to your answer.